# Button above the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I created a `TabbedPage` which opens the various pages that I created within my project.

```
<myapp:MainPage Title="Page1" IconImageSource="IC001.png" BackgroundColor="Gainsboro"></myapp:MainPage>
<myapp:DiaryPage Title="Page2" IconImageSource="IC002.png" BackgroundColor="Gainsboro"></myapp:MainPage>
```

Through this namespace on Android I can see the `NavigationBar` at the bottom of the screen.

```
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

I would like to be able to place a Custom Button above the `NavigationBar`, a button that is within my Page Layout and that covers a portion of the `NavigationBar`. it's possible?

Example of my page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             x:Class="MotiVApp.DiaryPage">

    <Grid>
      <Button/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Like a [TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar)?

Comment: [https://i.postimg.cc/qRDVSRMS/screenshot-1613585693758.jpg]

Comment: [Custom Tabs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/913fa7963273971c42ed97c3223eb212eff2d5c1/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/TabView/CustomTabsPage.xaml) from XCT could work, [more details](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/501) here.